# Error installing pandas v0.25.3 on a docker container with python3.6.2. Needed to install airflow v.1.10.2

Tags: pandas, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I'm building out a docker container and trying to get apache-airflow 1.10.2 to build with python 3.6.2 on an ubuntu:18.04 base image.

I have a Pipfile that I'm trying to install from inside of a python3.6.2 virtual env.

Here is the dockerfile I'm building on:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /app

# set the variables as per $(pyenv init -)
ENV LANG="C.UTF-8" \
    LC_ALL="C.UTF-8" 


RUN apt-get update &&  \
        apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        libbz2-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libncurses5-dev \
        libncursesw5-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        libssl1.0-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        # libssl-dev \
        llvm \
        make \
        netbase \
        pkg-config \
        # tk-dev \
        wget \
        xz-utils \
        zlib1g-dev \
        vim

RUN curl https://pyenv.run | bash && \
    echo 'export PATH="/root/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> /root/.bashrc

ENV PATH="/root/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

RUN eval "$(pyenv init -)" && \
    pyenv install 3.6.2 && \
    pyenv global 3.6.2

COPY . .
RUN pip install pipenv

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Then when I enter the docker container I run `pipenv shell` to create a python virtual env and then install packages via pip.

I get the following error message when trying to install Pandas, but I do have numpy v1.19.5 installed.

```
error: ‘NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘NPY_INOUT_ARRAY’?
       return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              NPY_INOUT_ARRAY
  pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:181:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:182:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   }
   ^
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
```

Any advice on how to go about this next would be great!

I've tried reinstalling numpy, and building out a new docker container again but this hasn't worked. Most of what I've seen online has just been using a new version, but I need to build out with these versions to mimic my production environment, and then I will upgrade at a later date. These airflow and pandas versions are currently running in an EC2 instance, so I know the packages are able download and build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to get pandas v0.25.3 installed you need to use numpy v1.18.5 (I previously had 1.19.5). Once I got the right version of numpy I'm able to install pandas and airflow

Comment: You can just install `pandas` and let it automatically chose the right `numpy` dependency. Playing manually with dependencies can indeed be tricky :-)